# When I play games that require high graphics I get white flickering

Tags: crash, hardware-failure, graphics

Alright my computer when i play games will flicker white across the screen and some games will even crash immediately after getting in the game, I only have the problem with games that require high graphics, I notice the white flicker in games like Minecraft but its barely noticeable so its not a problem, the white flickering started randomly while I was playing.

I've switched out every part of my pc except for the motherboard and Processor. I've redownloaded windows 3 times with different CD's, I've downloaded all the drivers and tried old and new ones with many parts that I could download drivers on.

My computer specs;
Asus M4a88t-m motherboard
Antec BP550 Plus 550W
G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) RAM
Nividia 550ti 1gb 192bit video card
Anthon 2 3.2ghz x3 CPU am3

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card should handle the games fine. Since you also fully formatted your PC replacing the drivers and everything that could cause such problems several times, the problem is most likely a hardware one.

You should check if the graphics card is getting enough power - try switching it on a different rail of the power supply, or try it with a different power supply altogether if possible.

If the problem persists, try your graphics card in another computer - if the same problem appears there as well, the card is most likely broken.

The problem might also be caused by other components, but this should be unlikely. You might want to test your RAM with Memtest, and perhaps run a stress test on your CPU.